# Problems to generate a nested image with the turtle module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, turtle-graphics

I have an exercise in which I must generate the image one using the turtle module in Python. And I managed to generate the pattern of a certain form but failed to obtain the final result.
This is the code that allows me to generate my image so far.

[image]

```
import turtle

def generarVentana(titulo, color):
    w = turtle.Screen()
    w.title(titulo)
    w.bgcolor(color)

    return w

def generarTortuga(color, tamano):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.color(color)
    t.pensize(tamano)

    return t

def generaArista2(tortuga, lado_base, iteraciones):

    ang_abajo = 275
    ang_izquierda = 185
    ang_arriba = 95
    ang_derecha = 5

    for i in range (iteraciones):
        for angulo in [ang_abajo, ang_izquierda, ang_arriba, ang_derecha]:
            print("heading inicio", tortuga.heading())
            tortuga.setheading(0)
            print("heading final", tortuga.heading())
            tortuga.left(angulo)
            tortuga.forward(lado_base)
            lado_base += 10
        print(ang_abajo)
        print(ang_izquierda)
        print(ang_arriba)
        print(ang_derecha)
        ang_abajo += 2
        ang_izquierda += 2
        ang_arriba += 2
        ang_derecha += 2


wn = generarVentana("Ejercicio 5", "lightgreen")

tess = generarTortuga("blue", 2)

tess.speed("fastest")

generaArista2(tess, 5, 20)

wn.mainloop()
```

**This is the result I get with my code**

[image: imagen-obtenida]

I would be grateful if you **could indicate that part of the code should be modified so that I can generate the desired pattern** since I have changed the size of the lines as well as the angle but I cannot generate the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say that you're over thinking the problem.  Say we toss 2/3 (of the non-`print`) statements in `generaArista2` and simply do:

```
def generaArista2(tortuga, lado_base, iteraciones):

    for _ in range(iteraciones):
        tortuga.right(89)
        tortuga.forward(lado_base)

        lado_base += 3

# ...

generaArista2(tess, 2, 99)
```

This appears to get us closer to where you want to be:

[image]

What more needs to be done?  What was all that extra code doing for you?  Bottom line: start simple.

Comment: Thank you very much  @cdlane,

I really do not understand how I could fulfill so much.
I guess I get too angry at the problem, luckily I came to ask for help. Now if I sleep peacefully XD